# How to Automate a XACML String Manipulation Function in ALFA?

Tags: authorization, xacml, abac, alfa

We got a request to write a set of rules in a policy which should generate a detailed log message, both for Permit and Deny condition. The resulting log output is a construction of several attributes, or transferred from the XACML request input, or from the PIP Java routines, where we get additional attributes like UTC log event time and the service status of the data sources, among a set of attributes from the database. All information should be transported to the PEP by means of XACML obligations, which converts the String into a final database logging step.

Is there a way to create a reusable function in ALFA language that groups all required String manipulation statements in a callable manner, in a similar way to Java programmatic function, avoiding a writing of redundant code sections.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't a way in the current version of ALFA to define a custom function that would group all that you are interested in.

However, you could very well define a rule that contains the advice / obligation with all the logic and then reference the rule in all the places you need it. In ALFA, you can reference Rule elements (something that is not possible in XML/XACML)

Here is an example:

```
namespace so{
    import Attributes.*
    attribute messageContent{
        category = environmentCat
        id = "messageContent"
        type = string
    }
    obligation message = "message"
    /**
     * Reusable rule with obligation pattern
     */
    rule giveReason{
        deny
        on deny {
            obligation message{
                subjectId = subjectId
                currentDateTime = currentDateTime
                messageContent = "Hi, "+stringOneAndOnly(subjectId)+
                                 ". You cannot do action "+
                                 stringOneAndOnly(Attributes.actionId)+
                                 " on "+stringOneAndOnly(resourceId)+
                                 " at "+stringFromDateTime(dateTimeOneAndOnly(currentDateTime))+"."
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Your policies
     */
     policyset somePS{
         apply firstApplicable
         policy example1{
             apply firstApplicable
             /**
              * Other rules go here
              */
             giveReason // link to common rule
         }
         policy example2{
             apply firstApplicable
             /**
              * Other rules go here
              */
             giveReason // link to common rule
         }
     }
}
```